# Can I override the alert/prompt dialog boxes behavior in a WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, dialog, webbrowser-control

Is there something similar to Qt [`QWebView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html)'s [`QWebPage`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebpage.html) where I can override the [`method`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebpage.html#javaScriptConfirm) that gets called every time a prompt/alert is about to be displayed? I've been told about to implement `IDocHostShowUI` but even after done some search, I have no idea how do this with [`WebBrowser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Does Paulo Morgado's answer help? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8b0712ca-0b92-4e3d-a243-27af57a57213/idochostshowui-problem-c-webbrowser?forum=ieextensiondevelopment

Comment: @TEK: Yep, it does! Post as answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paulo Morgado provided an answer on the [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8b0712ca-0b92-4e3d-a243-27af57a57213/idochostshowui-problem-c-webbrowser?forum=ieextensiondevelopment).

Code and comments from that post are provided below for future readers.

> It's the WebBrowserSite, not the WebBrowser that needs to implement
>   IDocHostShowUI

```
 using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 namespace WebBrowserMessageBox
 {
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
       public int x;
       public int y;
    }



    [ComImport, Guid("C4D244B0-D43E-11CF-893B-00AA00BDCE1A"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
      public interface IDocHostShowUI
      {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        [PreserveSig]
        int ShowMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpstrText,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpstrCaption,
          int dwType,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpstrHelpFile,
          int dwHelpContext,
          out int lpResult);
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int ShowHelp(
      IntPtr hwnd,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszHelpFile,
      int uCommand,
      int dwData,
      POINT ptMouse,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object pDispatchObjectHit);
  }

  public class ShowMessageEventArgs : EventArgs
 {
    public ShowMessageEventArgs(string text, string caption, int type, string helpFile, int helpContext)
    {
    }

    public bool Handled { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; private set; }
    public int HelpContext { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public string Caption { get; private set; }
    public string HelpFile { get; private set; }
  }

  public class MyWebBrowser : global::System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
  {
    protected class MyWebBrowserSite : global::System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.WebBrowserSite, IDocHostShowUI
    {
      private readonly MyWebBrowser host;

      public MyWebBrowserSite(MyWebBrowser host)
        : base(host)
      {
        this.host = host;
      }

      public int ShowMessage(IntPtr hwnd, string lpstrText, string lpstrCaption, int dwType, string lpstrHelpFile, int dwHelpContext, out int lpResult)
      {
        var e = new ShowMessageEventArgs(lpstrText, lpstrCaption, dwType, lpstrHelpFile, dwHelpContext);
        this.host.OnShowMessage(e);

        if (e.Handled)
        {
          lpResult = e.Result;
          return 0;
        }
        else
        {
          lpResult = 0;
          return 1;
        }
      }

      public int ShowHelp(IntPtr hwnd, string pszHelpFile, int uCommand, int dwData, POINT ptMouse, object pDispatchObjectHit)
      {
        return 1;
      }
    }

    protected override System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserSiteBase CreateWebBrowserSiteBase()
    {
      return new MyWebBrowserSite(this);
    }

    protected virtual void OnShowMessage(ShowMessageEventArgs e)
    {
      var handler = this.Events["ShowMessage"] as EventHandler<ShowMessageEventArgs>;

      if (handler != null)
      {
        handler(this, e);
      }
    }

    public event EventHandler<ShowMessageEventArgs> ShowMessage
    {
      add { this.Events.AddHandler("ShowMessage", value); }
      remove { this.Events.RemoveHandler("ShowMessage", value); }
    }
  }

  public static class Program
  {
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
      var webBrowser = new MyWebBrowser
      {
        Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill,
        DocumentText = @"<html><head><body><script language='JScript'>alert(""test"")</script></body></head></html>"
      };
      webBrowser.ShowMessage += (sender, e) =>
      {
        e.Result = 0;
        e.Handled = true;
      };

      var form = new global::System.Windows.Forms.Form
      {
        Controls = { webBrowser }
      };

      global::System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(form);
    }
  }
}
```

*Please note I am not the author of this code.*